# Google Login Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, google-signin

I have a WordPress site. currently I have login functionality with google. but when I am doing login with google its add me in as a user and populating me admin dashboard user section.

I only need to verify with google login and redirect to another page, no need to add in our db or in user section.

can any one help me here how could I achieve this

I tried with nextend social plug in and there is no option to configure the same.